# Transferring property of Hall subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $K\le G$, $H$ is a Hall $\pi$-subgroup of $G$ such that $HK=KH$. Show that $H\cap K$ is a Hall $\pi$-subgroup of $K$.

---

WLOG, I assume that $G=HK$ because $H$ is a Hall $\pi$-subgroup of $HK$. Now $H$, $K\triangleleft HK$. So $KH/H \simeq K/K\cap H$ yields $(K:H\cap K)=(KH:H)=(HK:H)$ is a $\pi'd$-number. For another part, we have $|H\cap K|=\frac {|H||K|}{HK}$, but I am stuck here to prove $|H\cap K|$ is a $\pi d$-number as $|H|$.

Please help, thank you!

Comment: It is not necessarily true that $H,K \lhd HK$, so some of your argument is invalid. But it is true that $|H \cap K| = |H||K|/|HK|$ and the result follows from that.

Comment: @DerekHolt I got it. Thank you!